# Is it possible to remove these actions from woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I try to use remove_action to remove actions from woocommerce, but can't figure out how to do it.

First I try this:

```
global $wc_admin_profile;

    remove_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $wc_admin_profile, 'add_customer_meta_fields' ) );
    remove_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $wc_admin_profile, 'add_customer_meta_fields' ) );
```

and I also try this:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpdev_170663_remove_parent_theme_stuff', 0 );
function wpdev_170663_remove_parent_theme_stuff() {
    global $wc_admin_profile;

    remove_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $wc_admin_profile, 'add_customer_meta_fields' ) );
    remove_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $wc_admin_profile, 'add_customer_meta_fields' ) );
}
```

but they don't work.

```
/**
 * WC_Admin_Profile Class
 */
class WC_Admin_Profile {
    /**
     * Hook in tabs.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $this, 'add_customer_meta_fields' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $this, 'add_customer_meta_fields' ) );
        add_action( 'personal_options_update', array( $this, 'save_customer_meta_fields' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array( $this, 'save_customer_meta_fields' ) );
        add_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $this, 'add_api_key_field' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $this, 'add_api_key_field' ) );
        add_action( 'personal_options_update', array( $this, 'generate_api_key' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array( $this, 'generate_api_key' ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for doing a bit of necromancy on this, but I found a much better solution is to use the filter `woocommerce_customer_meta_fields`.

Apply it like so:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', function($fields) {
   return [];
});
```

By returning an empty array inside this filter, this will cause the foreach loop in `WC_Admin_Profile::add_customer_meta_fields` to terminate and thus prevent any output.

You can verify this by examining how the filter is applied and processed in the `WC_Admin_Profile` class in woocommerce at `/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-profile.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If no solution applied then try

```
remove_all_actions( $tag, $priority );
```

It will remove actions

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these actions by overriding the WC_Admin_Profile Woocommerce core class. 
You can do that by creating an new plugin(creating new php file) and place it inside mu-plugins. 
The plugin will contain the definition of the `WC_Admin_Profile`

```php
class WC_Admin_Profile {

}
return new WC_Admin_Profile();
```

Now you are free to define you own code inside the newly created class.

We alle know that plugins inside mu-plugins directories execute before any other plugins. So don't try to solve it by placing code inside functions.php inside your active theme directory.
Check this scheme [Code execution order scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbncr.png) 
I have faced the same problem and I could solve it by doing that. This solution works 100% because in the `class-wc-admin-profile.php` which placed in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin` you have a check which verify is the class already is defined or not.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Admin_Profile' ) ) :
```

So because you have already defined your own class, it will never run the class from the Woocommerce core.

I hope it helps :)